# CSS3 animation - image keeps moving when div's width changes

Tags: css, animation

I'm trying to mimic sites like: http://shiz.co/ and http://www.maison-vignaux.com/work

The way the images show up, it's like they're not moving, but more of it gets shown in an interval. I want this type of animation. Right now, my image moves rather than having more of it show up like the sites above.

I have no idea how to accomplish this.

Here's my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z7ukk6kb/ (disregard the name of the animation)

EDIT: problem was the background position on the div. now it does what I want.

```
 <div class="parallax-elem">
   <div class="img"></div>
 </div>

$('.img').addClass('slide-top');
```

My CSS:

```
.slide-top {
  -webkit-animation: slide-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
          animation: slide-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
}

@keyframes slide-top {
  0% {
      width:0;
  }
  100% {
      width:100%;
  }
}

.parallax-elem {
  overflow:hidden;
  position: absolute;
  height:600px;
  width:100%;
}

.parallax-elem:after {
  content:"";
  background-color:#eee;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:10;
}

.img {
  background:url('http://media.nj.com/entertainment_impact_dining/photo/coffee-stock-photo-0e8b300f42157b6f.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  z-index:11;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: How do I do it? Thanks for the downvote. I'm just trying to learn. I provided my code and the current animation it's doing.

Comment: see [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - especially "Describe the problem. "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement. Tell us what the expected behavior should be."

Comment: I fricken did that m8. i said their image shows up more in an interval . if you looked at my fiddle, you'll see my image is moving.

Comment: You're new to this website. It is not uncommon to miss some of the practices we perform here. No need to get all offensive about it, take the critique, adapt, as frustration as that might be (we've all been through it). In the end, it will benefit and maintain the quality of SO :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `background-position` from `.img`.

Since you have set `background-position: center center`, as the width of the `div` increases during the animation, the background image keeps adjusting to stay centered. That's the reason it keeps moving.

```js
$('.img').addClass('slide-top');
```

```css
.slide-top {
          animation: slide-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both infinite;
}


@keyframes slide-top {
  0% {
            width:0;
  }
  100% {
            width:100%;
  }
}

body {
  max-width:800px;
 margin:0 auto;
 position:relative;
}

.parallax-elem {
  overflow:hidden;
  position: absolute;
  height:600px;
  width:100%;
}

.parallax-elem:after {
  content:"";
  background-color:#eee;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:10;
}

.img {
  background:url('http://media.nj.com/entertainment_impact_dining/photo/coffee-stock-photo-0e8b300f42157b6f.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  z-index:11;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parallax-elem">
    <div class="img"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: that did it man, thank you. 

thought it was my keyframe animation. wouldn't have thought it was the background property

Thanks again!

Comment: @corporalpoon glad to know it was helpful. :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happens is because you use background-position center. And that is exactly what is is doing, it is aligning you image in the center. If you'd change is to `background-position: left center`, the problem is fixed, as you can see [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z7ukk6kb/1/).

You could also remove the *background-position* entirely, but then you will also loose you vertical alignment, you might not want that.

Also, you can make your animation a whole lot easier, you don't need keyframes:

```
.img{
    width: 0%;
    background-position: left center;
    animation: width 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940);
}
.img.slide-top{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: ah, thanks man! that is a lot cleaner. 

I wish I knew how to make really cool complex css3 animation sites like the ones I posted, but I don't really know where to start.

Comment: Well, you start with what you're doing right now ;) And just improve step by step.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this same effect using <video>? a width transition scales it in all directions just like a background image would if it had background-position:center center. it scales.

Comment: Sure. Add a video player in a div with overflow. But starting the video and animation at the same time wont be smooth

Comment: thanks for the response. i have it in the same type of div the images are in, with the video having the same animation properties, i.e width.

still scales though. but i guess if it's possible, i'll figure it out.

Comment: and yeah, i was gonna have a loader overlay until the video is ready I think